# Joomla makes my request wait for 5 seconds

Tags: php, joomla, wait

I have got a very strange problem regarding one of my Joomla websites. The webpage seems to wait before it loads the actual content. So I did some research and I found out that there is a particular file (index.php/en/) that makes my request wait for over 5 seconds. See the image below.

https://imgur.com/JqlkNYq

I run on the latest version of Joomla and I haven't got any issues on other sites with plugins or components (DJ Imageslider is the only component here) so I'm really confused in where the problem can lie. I'll keep researching the problem but I hope someone may have had the same problem that can help me with this issue.

Comment: Hey. You can (and probably should) directly embed that image in your post.

Comment: Note: This post has been posted on the Joomla forum as well: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=709&t=927738&p=3410513

Comment: Yeah same person. I also made a post on the Joomla forum as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the issue. There was a module which was completely not loading anymore and giving multiple errors. With the use of debugging in the Joomla website I could track the issue.